# How to rename a file under an unknown directory, using another directory's name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to rename a file (or copy it to a new name) based on a directory name, that is under an unknown directory name.

I have numerous dated folders, with sub-directories.  Under each sub-directory, is a file named `index.txt`. That txt file needs to be renamed or copied to the name of the directory above it. The name of each of the sub-directories is known so that can be used in the script if necessary.

*For example:*

```
>Tree C:\Test /f
C:\TEST
├───20170414124512
│   ├───Directory1
│   │       index.txt
│   │
│   ├───Directory2
│   │       index.txt
│   │
│   └───Directory3
│           index.txt
│  
└───20170414134345
    ├───Directory1
    │       index.txt
    │
    ├───Directory2
    │       index.txt
    │
    └───Directory3
            index.txt
```

*I need the end result to look like this:*

- C:\Test\20170414124512\Directory1\Directory1.txt
- C:\Test\20170414124512\Directory2\Directory2.txt
- C:\Test\20170414124512\Directory3\Directory3.txt
- C:\Test\20170414134345\Directory1\Directory1.txt
- C:\Test\20170414134345\Directory2\Directory2.txt
- C:\Test\20170414134345\Directory3\Directory3.txt

**Sorry, I should have included what I tried.  This is what I tried and it did not work.

for /D /R "C:\Test" %%a in (*) do echo ren "%%a\index.txt" "%%~Na.txt"

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you have problems with? Hint: check out the [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and learn to use its `/D` option as well as the `~` modifiers; type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text. Starting point: `for /D %%J in ("C:\Test\*") do for /D %%I in ("%%~fJ\*") do ren "%%~fI\index.txt" "%%~nI.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid trying to rename non existing index.txt files an additonal if to aschipl's suggestion should do:

```
@Echo off
for /D %%J in ("C:\Test\*"
  ) do for /D %%I in ("%%~fJ\*"
  ) do (
   If exist "%%~fI\index.txt" Echo ren "%%~fI\index.txt" "%%~nI.txt"
)
```

If the output looks OK, remove the echo in the last line:

```
ren "C:\Test\20170414124512\Directory1\index.txt" "Directory1.txt"
ren "C:\Test\20170414124512\Directory2\index.txt" "Directory2.txt"
ren "C:\Test\20170414124512\Directory3\index.txt" "Directory3.txt"
ren "C:\Test\20170414134345\Directory1\index.txt" "Directory1.txt"
ren "C:\Test\20170414134345\Directory2\index.txt" "Directory2.txt"
ren "C:\Test\20170414134345\Directory3\index.txt" "Directory3.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.
You could probably move it somewhere else as well if you want it.
This is a powershell script.

```
foreach($folder in Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse)
{
    if ($folder -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])
    {
        if($folder.Name -contains "Your Foldername")
        {
            $path = $folder.FullName
            Rename-Item "$path\index.txt" -NewName "Newname.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "u:\sourcedir\index.txt" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%r IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO REN "%%a" "%%~nr%%~xa"
)
```

All of which can be on one line if you wish. I used `u:\sourcedir\` as a test directory and The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Note that execution directly from the prompt and as lines with a batch file are different. The `metavariable` (loop-control variable) `%%x` must be referenced as `%%x` for a batch line and `%x` if executed from the command prompt. Since it makes little sense to repeatedly execute a line containing a `for` from the prompt (it's easier to create a batch file), I post the batch-file version. User's responsibility to adjust for direct-from-prompt if desired.

In memory, create a directory list in `/b` basic form `/s` scan subdirectories `/a-d` but don't deliver directorynames of files matching `index.txt`. Assign each name to `%%a` (the "delims=" ensures the entire line is assigned by turning off the default delimiters). Detect the directoryname by repeating the parsing operation on the drive and path part of `%%a` (`%%~dpa`) made to look like a filename by adding `.`. Then construct the `ren` command using the from-name (all of `%%a`) and the to-name (name and extension only) using the "name part" of `%%r` and the extension part of `%%a` (which we actually know is `.txt` since that's what is specified in the `dir` command) - all neatly enclosed in quotes so that `ren` could cope syntactically with separators like <kbd>Space</kbd> appearing anywhere in the names being juggled.